# Разрешение на установку приложений

Tags: java, android

какое разрешение надо прописать в AndroidManifest.xml, для установки приложений из этого источника?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для установки из неизвестных источников нужно запрашивать разрешение программно. Но для начала нужно в манифесте установить тоже [разрешение](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

Перед самим процессом запроса разрешения можно [проверить](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#canRequestPackageInstalls()) можно ли вообще такое разрешение запрашивать:

```
getPackageManager().canRequestPackageInstalls()
```

Теперь касательно программного запроса разрешения на установку приложений. Делается это все через интент ([доки](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES)):

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES));
```

либо вы можете запросить настройки для конкретного приложения на разрешение установки:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES, Uri.parse("package:your.application.package")));
```

Так же если есть файл `.apk` который вы хотите установить то можно это сделать таким способом:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
intent.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "your.application.package.fileprovider", new File("/path/to/your/apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

startActivity(intent);
```

Так же можно установить разрешения в манифесте на изменение настроек безопасности:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
```

[Вот тут документация](https://source.android.com/security/#the-android-permission-model-accessing-protected-apis) про саму безопасность android системы. Для проверки разрешения установки из неизвестных источников можно сделать переменную:

```
boolean isNonPlayAppAllowed = Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS) == 1;
```

и проверять при попытке установить приложение со стороны:

```
if (!isNonPlayAppAllowed) {
    startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS));
}
```

Вот есть подобные вопросы [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026554/turn-on-unknown-sources-setting-programmatically) и [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333602/programmatically-find-whether-installing-from-unknown-sources-is-allowed).